# Retrieving top 50 rows from Table using LINQ

Tags: linq-to-sql

Am new to LINQ, and am trying to retrieve the top 50 rows of a particular table.

In SQL Server using an actual query i coudl say "Select TOP 50 from Transactions" , but not sure how i need to do that with LinQ

Any pointers that could help ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
var list = db.Transactions.Take(50);
```

Of course this doesn't include any ordering or sorting which your query will probably need.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a basic example doing a select with a where and getting 50 records:

```
var transactions = (from t in db.Transactions
    where t.Name.StartsWith("A")
    select t).Take(50);
```

Using other syntax:

```
var transactions = db.Transactions.Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith("A")).Take(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do it.

```
collection = (from e in table select e).Top(50)
```

EDIT: Oops, I knew it didn't look right.

```
collection = (from e in table select e).Take(50)
```